# Returning first sentence from variable in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have found a similar thread already where I got:

```
$sentence = preg_replace('/(.*?[?!.](?=\s|$)).*/', '\\1', $string);
```

This doesn't seem to work in my function though:

```
<?function first_sentence($content) {
    $content = html_entity_decode(strip_tags($content));   
    $content = preg_replace('/(.*?[?!.](?=\s|$)).*/', '\\1', $content);
    return $content;


}?>
```

It seems to be not taking into account the first sentence when a sentence ends as the end of a paragraph. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include a link to the original thread where you got the code please? Never mind, I think I got it, [Does anyone have a PHP snippet of code for grabbing the first “sentence” in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135467/does-anyone-have-a-php-snippet-of-code-for-grabbing-the-first-sentence-in-a-str).

Comment: Have you looked at any of the other "first sentence with regex" questions, like this one, [First Sentence Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569091/first-sentence-regex)?

Comment: This one looks promising /^.{150,}?[.?!]+(?=\s|$)/ but not sure how I'd incorporate it into a function

Comment: What do you mean when the sentence ends as the result of a paragraph? Is there still a period in this case or is it using a different delimeter?

Comment: What's the function of '\\1'? I'm trying to use this as well, but when there's multiple paragraphs present, I get more than 1 sentence returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's correct syntax, sorry for my first response:

```
function firstSentence($string) {
      $sentences = explode(".", $string);
      return $sentences[0];
}
```

Comment: This should absolutely not be the accepted solution. Sverri Olsen has it right.

Comment: I'd wager that more than 70.4 % of all sentences are not terminated by a dot!!! Am I right? I suppose I am.

Comment: A decade later, and I quite agree with others. My solution is terrible.

Answer (score 6):

```
/**
 * Get the first sentence of a string.
 *
 * If no ending punctuation is found then $text will
 * be returned as the sentence. If $strict is set
 * to TRUE then FALSE will be returned instead.
 *
 * @param  string  $text   Text
 * @param  boolean $strict Sentences *must* end with one of the $end characters
 * @param  string  $end    Ending punctuation
 * @return string|bool     Sentence or FALSE if none was found
 */
function firstSentence($text, $strict = false, $end = '.?!') {
    preg_match("/^[^{$end}]+[{$end}]/", $text, $result);
    if (empty($result)) {
        return ($strict ? false : $text);
    }
    return $result[0];
}

// Returns "This is a sentence."
$one = firstSentence('This is a sentence. And another sentence.');

// Returns "This is a sentence"
$two = firstSentence('This is a sentence');

// Returns FALSE
$three = firstSentence('This is a sentence', true);
```

Comment: I'm curious to understand the return strict false stuff around an empty $result.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need n number of sentences, you can use the following code. 
I adapted code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22337095 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494335

```
/**
 * Get n number of first sentences of a string.
 *
 * If no ending punctuation is found then $text will
 * be returned as the sentence. If $strict is set
 * to TRUE then FALSE will be returned instead.
 *
 * @param  string  $text   Text
 * int     $no_sentences   Number of sentences to extract
 * @param  boolean $strict Sentences *must* end with one of the $end characters
 * @param  string  $end    Ending punctuation
 * @return string|bool     Sentences or FALSE if none was found
 */

function firstSentences($text, $no_sentences, $strict = false , $end = '.?!;:') {

    $result = preg_split('/(?<=['.$end.'])\s+/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    if (empty($result)) {
        return ($strict ? false : $text);
    }

    $ouput = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $no_sentences; $i++) {
        $ouput .= $result[$i].' ';
    }
    return $ouput;

}
```