# Explode a paragraph into sentences in PHP

Tags: php, string, explode, text-segmentation

I have been using

```
explode(".",$mystring)
```

to split a paragraph into sentences. However this doen't cover sentences that have been concluded with different punctuation such as ! ? : ;

Is there a way of using an array as a delimiter instead of a single character? Alternativly is there another neat way of splitting using various punctuation?

I tried

```
explode(("." || "?" || "!"),$mystring)
```

hopefully but it didn't work...

Comment: use regular expression to match pattern and store the value in a variable , pass that variable as parameter to explode

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032210/php-sentence-boundaries-detection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
preg_split('/\.|\?|!/',$mystring);
```

or (simpler):

```
preg_split('/[.?!]/',$mystring);
```

Comment: This method removes full stops etc from the final string.

Comment: Good solution, but doesn't work if "Mr. Smith" is in the sentence.

Comment: @VictorStoddard for what it's worth - i addressed this in my answer.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) combined with a [PCRE lookahead condition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split the string after each occurance of `.`, `;`, `:`, `?`, `!`, .. while keeping the actual punctuation intact:

Code:

```
$subject = 'abc sdfs.    def ghi; this is an.email@addre.ss! asdasdasd? abc xyz';
// split on whitespace between sentences preceded by a punctuation mark
$result = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!;:])\s+/', $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc sdfs.
    [1] => def ghi;
    [2] => this is an.email@addre.ss!
    [3] => asdasdasd?
    [4] => abc xyz
)
```

You can also add a blacklist for abbreviations (Mr., Mrs., Dr., ..) that should *not* be split into own sentences by inserting a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
$subject = 'abc sdfs.   Dr. Foo said he is not a sentence; asdasdasd? abc xyz';
// split on whitespace between sentences preceded by a punctuation mark
$result = preg_split('/(?<!Mr.|Mrs.|Dr.)(?<=[.?!;:])\s+/', $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc sdfs.
    [1] => Dr. Foo said he is not a sentence;
    [2] => asdasdasd?
    [3] => abc xyz
)
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. How about if sentence ends with number, such as: "This is my test 40. But also new one."

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you actually want the punctuations marks with the end result, have you tried:

```
 $mystring = str_replace("?","?---",str_replace(".",".---",str_replace("!","!---",$mystring)));
 $tmp = explode("---",$mystring);
```

Which would leave your punctuation marks in tact.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_split('/\s+|[.?!]/',$string);
```

A possible problem might be if there is an email address as it could split it onto a new line half way through.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `preg_split`

```
$sentences = preg_split("/[.?!:;]+/", $mystring);
```

Please note this will remove the punctuations. If you would like to strip out leading or trailing whitespace as well

```
$sentences = preg_split("/[.?!:;]+\s+?/", $mystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and give it a regex like [\.|\?!] to split on

Answer (score 0):

```
$mylist = preg_split("/[.?!:;]/", $mystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple delimiters for explode. That's what `preg_split();` is for. But even then, it explodes at the delimiter, so you will get sentences returned without the punctuation marks.
You can take preg_split a step farther and flag it to return them in their own elements with PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE and then run some loop to implode sentence and following punctation mark in the returned array, or just use `preg_match_all();`:

```
preg_match_all('~.*?[?.!]~s', $string, $sentences);
```