# PHP Get last n sentences from a string

Tags: php, mysql, paragraphs

Let's say I have the string below

```
$string = 'PHP Coding.
Hello World!
Merry Christmas!
Happy New Year!
Merry Super Early Next Christmas?
I want Pizza, and Cake
Hehehe
Hohohoho';
```

How do I get the last n sentences from the string, for example, the last 3 sentences, which should give the following output:

```
I want Pizza, and Cake
Hehehe
Hohohoho
```

Edit: I'm using data from sql

Comment: split on linebreaks, giving you an array, then pop however many lines you want from the end of the array.

Comment: php explode() function should help you split the string. I would suggest reading the PHP string manual though before asking for help.

Comment: @MarcB Sure, if there were line breaks to start with. OP's code is set inside a variable producing `PHP Coding. Hello World! Merry Christmas! Happy New Year! Merry Super Early Next Christmas? I want Pizza, and Cake Hehehe Hohohoho`

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494176/explode-a-paragraph-into-sentences-in-php

Comment: @fred: there's line breaks. it's a multi-line string definition, after all.

Comment: @MarcB Multi-line definition, yes I agree. I might have taken your initial comment out of context. However, to me, a line break consists of the ever so famous hidden `\n` which isn't present in OP's long string.

Comment: then it'd have to be `$foo = "bar\nbaz"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $string = 'PHP Coding.
            Hello World!
            Merry Christmas!
            Happy New Year!
            Merry Super Early Next Christmas?
            I want Pizza, and Cake
            Hehehe
            Hohohoho';

    list($sentence[], $sentence[], $sentence[]) = array_slice(explode(PHP_EOL, $string), -3, 3);

    print_r($sentence);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [2] => Hohohoho [1] => Hehehe [0] => I want Pizza, and Cake )
```

**EDIT :**

Here you can define how many sentence you want from the back:

```
<?php

    $string = 'PHP Coding.
            Hello World!
            Merry Christmas!
            Happy New Year!
            Merry Super Early Next Christmas?
            I want Pizza, and Cake
            Hehehe
            Hohohoho';

    $n = 3;

    $sentence = array_slice(explode(PHP_EOL, $string), -($n), $n);
    $sentence = array_slice(explode(PHP_EOL, nl2br($string)), -($n), $n); // Use this for echoing out in HTML
    print_r($sentence);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => I want Pizza, and Cake [1] => Hehehe [2] => Hohohoho )
```

Comment: are there any ways to do them in a single line?

Comment: *"are there any ways to do them in a single line?"* - Too easy.

Comment: @Aesreal `foreach($sentence as $var){ echo $var . " "; }` producing `I want Pizza, and Cake Hehehe Hohohoho`

Comment: @Aesreal What do you mean with: `a single line`? You can write your entire script on one line!

Comment: *Hm,* I was under the impression OP wanted the output to be on a single line.

Comment: @Rizier123 It's still not working thou, I've tried using nl2br($string) instead. this data is actually obtained from sql, and as such it is as Fred -ii said, PHP_EOL is not working

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup, i wanted them to be in a single line like what you did, but if that is not possible then a function is also fine, just that none of the answers are working right now!

Comment: @Aesreal What Rizier originally posted as an answer and adding my `foreach` should have worked. You may have to update your question with the SQL you're using in order to achieve your goal. By "not working"; can you define that? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Ahhhh, its working now! had some syntax problems with it. =.= sorry for wasting your time, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'PHP Coding.
Hello World!
Merry Christmas!
Happy New Year!
Merry Super Early Next Christmas?
I want Pizza, and Cake
Hehehe
Hohohoho';



function getLast($string, $n){
    $splits = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
    return array_slice($splits, -$n, count($splits));
}

$result = getLast($string, 2);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: *"Guessing the separator is `\n`"* - There are none, believe me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right, there are no separators, hence the linebreaks the people above suggested are all not going to work as well.