# How to read article text file to string?

Tags: php, function

I want PHP read my article text file like this.

sample text file :

```
OMG! Where is my right hand.

I try to find my right hand but I can't see it.

please tell me how to find it.
```

Now I have this function code

```
function getContent($file_path,$path=''){
        $file_path = $file_path;
        if(file_exists('./'.$file_path)){
            $f_read = fopen($path.$file_path,'r');
            $rs = "";
            while (!feof($f_read)) {
                $rs .= fread($f_read, 8192);
            }
            fclose($f_read);
        }
        else{
            echo $rs = "Not Connect File !";
        }
        return($rs);
    }
```

after use that code :

```
OMG! Where is my right hand. I try to find my right hand but I can't see it. please tell me how to find it.
```

I want to use PHP function read first line to string1 and after first line is string2 like this

```
$string1 = "OMG! Where is my right hand."

$string2 = "I try to find my right hand but I can't see it.

    please tell me how to find it."
```

Help me please :)

Comment: Answerers: please read the question. The OP wants to read the first line into $string1 and the rest of the file into $string2 - you don't seem to be addressing that 8and why did he get a downvote?)

Answer (score 0):

In order to to read the first line into $string1 and the rest of the file into $string2 ...

Read the first line, as you do above, then call [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the rest.

Use the `offset` parameter to tell file_get_contents() to start reading after the end of the first line (pass the string length of the first line).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for splitting your paragraph into string and also assign the character (like period, comma, etc.) from where do you want the paragraph to split.

```
preg_split('/[.?!]/',$mystring);
```

You may refer this link for more information: [Explode a paragraph into sentences in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494176/explode-a-paragraph-into-sentences-in-php)

### or

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$string=@file_get_contents($path_name);` `$string=@explode("\n",$string); //for get each line.`

Answer (score -1):

try using `explode()` function of PHP

```
function getContent($file_path,$path=''){
            $file_path = $file_path;
            if(file_exists('./'.$file_path)){
                $f_read = fopen($path.$file_path,'r');
                $rs = "";
                while (!feof($f_read)) {
                    $rs .= fread($f_read, 8192);
                    $demo=explode('.', $rs);
                }
                fclose($f_read);
            }
            else{
                echo $rs = "Not Connect File !";
            }
            return($demo);//result wiil be stored in $demo array like $demo[0], $demo[1]
        }
```