# php - preg_split() with multiple patterns not splitting quoted string

Tags: php, regex, string, split, string-parsing

I need to split a paragraph into sentences.
That's where i got a bit confused with the regex.

I have already referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494176) to which this Q is marked as a duplicate to. but the issue here is different.

**Here is a example of the string i need to split :**

> hello! how are you? how is life
>   live life, live free. "isnt it?"

**here is the code i tried :**

```
$sentence_array = preg_split('/([.!?\r\n|\r|\n])+(?![^"]*")/', $paragraph, -1);
```

**What i need is :**

```
array (  
  [0] => "hello"  
  [1] => "how are you"  
  [2] => "how is life"  
  [3] => "live life, live free"  
  [4] => ""isnt it?""  
)
```

**What i get is :**

```
array(
  [0] => "hello! how are you? how is life live life, live free. "isnt it?""
)
```

When i do not have any quotes in the string, the split works as required.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explode a paragraph into sentences in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494176/explode-a-paragraph-into-sentences-in-php)

Comment: You might try something like `'~"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*[.!?\r\n]\s*~'`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gToxu2/1).

Comment: @H2ONOCK i had seen that one. but my issue here is specific and different. I have the split working fine without quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your regular expression that the main of them is confusing group constructs with character classes. A pipe `|` in a character class means a `|` literally. It doesn't have any special meaning.

What you need is this:

```
("[^"]*")|[!?.]+\s*|\R+
```

This first tries to match a string enclosed in double quotation marks (and captures the content). Then tries to match any punctuation marks from `[!?.]` set to split on them. Then goes for any kind of newline characters if found.

PHP:

```
var_dump(preg_split('~("[^"]*")|[!?.]+\s*|\R+~', <<<STR
hello! how are you? how is life
live life, live free. "isnt it?"
STR
, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "how are you"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "how is life"
  [3]=>
  string(20) "live life, live free"
  [4]=>
  string(10) ""isnt it?""
}
```

Comment: thats a great solution... Thank you :)

Comment: i have a little doubt here. can i use it for all UTF-8 strings? When i used it over Hindi text, it creates a � character when it finds अ and breaks(splits right there). any idea?

Comment: Try to enable `u` flag i.e. `~("[^"]*")|[!?.]+\s*|\R+~u`

Comment: You just saved a day for me... you are a genius! :)

Comment: i have a small query here. How do we ignore parentheses`( )` as well?  I have tried this `|(\([^"]*\))`. didn't help!

Answer (score 1):

I view your problem of splitting based on certain punctuation already solved, except that it fails in the case of double quotes.  We can phrase a solution as saying that we should split when seeing such punctuation, *or* when seeing this punctuation followed by a double quote.

The split should happen when the previous character matches one of your markers *and* what follows is not a double quote, or the previous two characters should be a marker *and* a double quote.  This implies splitting on the following pattern, which uses lookarounds:

```
(?<=[.!?\r\n])(?=[^"])|(?<=[.!?\r\n]")(?=.)
```

Code sample:

```
$input = "hello! how \"are\" \"you?\" how is life\nlive life, live free. \"isnt it?\"";
$sentence_array = preg_split('/(?<=[.!?\r\n])(?=[^"])|(?<=[.!?\r\n]\")(?=.)/', $input, -1);
print_r($sentence_array);

Array ( [0] => hello! [1] => how "are" "you?" [2] => how is life
    [3] => live life, live free. [4] => "isnt it?" )
```

Comment: OP wants to match sentence end punctuation outside of `"`s. Lookarounds won't help, your solution will fail in many cases.

Comment: I have a small issue here, the `\r\n`, `\r` and `\n` are still in the string now. everything else is great. thank you Tim.

Comment: I don't have a fix for that.  I can only suggest removing them afterwards.  The lookaround trick I used does not consume anything, this is why it leaves the double quotes untouched.  But this also means that newlines/carriage returns would also not be removed.