# Splitting paragraph into sentences keeping the punctuations - not a dup

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Here us a point i am stuck again using regular expression with `PHP` `preg_split()` function.

**Here is the code :**

```
preg_split('~("[^"]*")|[!?.।]+\s*|\R+~u', $paragraph, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

I am trying to split a paragraph into sentences. This code does the job for me.
here is a link to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551031/php-preg-split-with-multiple-patterns-not-splitting-quoted-string)

But, now I need to keep the punctuation intact(the question marks, full stop etc.).

using the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` is supposed to have done that job but somehow it's not working that way. I get only sentences, without the full-stop or question marks.

Comment: Could you please post a test case? A not working one, and the expected result.

Comment: Use `\K` as in `("[^"]*")|[!?.।]+\K\s*|\R+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement doesn't need `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`. It's helpful when you need them to be returned as individual matches. In this case you need `\K`:

```
<?php

var_dump(preg_split('~("[^"]*")|[!?.।]+\K\s*|\R+~u', <<<STR
hello! how are you? how is life
live life, live free. "isnt it?"
STR
, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "hello!"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "how are you?"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "how is life"
  [3]=>
  string(21) "live life, live free."
  [4]=>
  string(10) ""isnt it?""
}
```