# Extract a phrase from a string in php

Tags: php

I have a string, extracted from the database, witch contains more phrases. I need to extract only first phrase witch is ending with a dot. somthing like this:
**$string** = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."; 
 
 and the result to be: **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.**

Thanks in advance for idei(I am new in php).

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Search for the dot, split it, take the first part, done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning first sentence from variable in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554375/returning-first-sentence-from-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

```
$phrases = explode('.', $string, 2);
echo $phrases[0];
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/HNavvkkn)**

Comment: You forgot to add an dot at the end :p `echo $phrases[0] . ".";`

Comment: You can use the 3rd param `limit` to prevent processing the rest of the string unnecessarily.

Comment: @LazKarimov it would need to be a limit of 2 for it to work.

Comment: Yes, that was it!, Laz Karimov. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$explode = explode(".", $string, 1);
echo $explode[0] . ".";
```

edit: Laz beat me to it, slow I am :p

Comment: As I mentioned above, you can use the 3rd param `limit` to prevent processing the rest of the string unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks Scott for a great addition :) I'll add it to my example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explode it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$firstSentence = explode(".", $string, 2);
echo $firstSentence[0] . ".";
```

Edit to add `.` to end of echo.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first find the position of the first dot. Then read the string up to and including the dot.

```
$lorem  = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...';
$dotpos = strpos($lorem, '.');
$phrase = substr($lorem, 0, $dotpos + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Database level solution:

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('your.text.here', '.', 1)
```

Comment: Did they ask for SQL code?

Comment: The question is tagged as `php`, and they use PHP code in the question. At no time was SQL mentioned.

Comment: "I have a string, extracted from the database" I posted sql referring to this.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`substr()`** and **`strpos()`** in PHP

```
<?php
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
echo (substr($string,0,strpos($string,'.')+1));
```